# polymorphism error: redefinition of a pointer (C++)

Tags: c++, class, polymorphism

I have included

```
#ifndef FileName_H
#define FileName_H
...
#endif
```

within all of my header files. In my `main.cpp`, I would like to use polymorphism of a class `Worker`:

```
Worker * w = NULL;
w = new Employee(001,"Tom",3);
w->showInfo();
delete w;

Worker * w = NULL;
w = new Manager(002,"Bob",1);
w->showInfo();
delete w;

Worker * w = NULL;
w = new Boss(003,"Ann",2);
w->showInfo();
delete w;
```

However, the `error: redefinition of 'w'` always occurs. I have included `#ifndef` statements, and I have deleted the pointer and set it `NULL` before reusing it. I don't know why this error can still occur. Could you give me some possible reasons or clues?

Comment: I clearly researched online. But most solutions are about the `#ifndef` statements.

Comment: Just leave out the `Worker` type in subsequent assignments of the variable? Nothing to do with your header guard `#ifndef`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ah you are right. Couldn't believe I overlooked it. Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but don’t initialize a pointer to `NULL` and immediately assign it a new value. Just assign the value in the first place: `Worker *w = new Employee(001, “Tom”, 3);`. Also, be careful of constants with leading zeros. 001 is **octal**. You’ll run into trouble with 008, and the value of 010 is 8.

Comment: @PeteBecker This is very helpful because I came across the number problem indeed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly what the error message says.

```
Worker * w = NULL;
w = new Employee(001,"Tom",3);
w->showInfo();
delete w;

Worker * w = NULL; // <<<<<<< here's the problem 
w = new Manager(002,"Bob",1);
w->showInfo();
delete w;
```

The second assignment to the pointer redefines the pointer variable, which isn't allowed within the same scope.
Your code should look like this instead:

```
Worker * w = NULL;
w = new Employee(001,"Tom",3);
w->showInfo();
delete w;

w = new Manager(002,"Bob",1); // No type declaration!
w->showInfo();
delete w;
```